# Protractor error "WebDriverError: Invalid timeout type specified: ms"

Tags: javascript, protractor

With no changes my protractor tests started giving this error:

```
[14:07:05] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[14:07:05] E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: Invalid timeout type specified: ms
```

Appreciate any help with this

Comment: For which browser you are facing this issue? Is it for all the supported browser or any specific one?

Comment: I tried on Chrome and IE and so far I see the issue only on IE with 5.0.0+ versions. With lower versions it's working fine.

Comment: Yup. Faced the same issue myself with 5.1.2. And shared some info on your github ticket too. Hope it gets resolved

Comment: I too hope it gets resolved soon bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with Internet Explorer.
Downgrading protractor from 5.1.2 to 5.0.0 worked for me.
(5.1.0, 5.1.1 and 5.1.2 seem to have the bug)

See this bug here:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4445

Comment: Yup the same I have also observed.

Comment: By the way it was I who raised the issue there as I needed a quick response from the community as that bug was not allowing me to go any further with my scripts.

Comment: I think it is not a problem with version 5.1.2 of protractor itself but with one of its dependencies (selenium server, ie driver) that has been updated. so only downgrading the selenium version might be sufficient as well.

Comment: 3.5.1 of the ie driver server also not solved the problem - but using 3.4.0 worked. You just have to use `webdriver-manager update --ie --versions.standalone 3.4.0 --versions.ie 3.4.0` and it will work - even with newest protractor version

Answer (score 2):

Find out the selenium standalone version you are using. I had the same problem with selenium stand alone server 3.5.0 and IE driver 3.5.0 (in case this problem is in IE). I downgraded the versions to selenium standalone 3.4.0 and IE driver 3.4.0 and it is working.

To Downgrade follow these steps:

Clean the webdrivers already installed:

`webdriver-manager clean`

Update the webdriver with specific version:

`webdriver-manager update --ie --versions.standalone=3.4.0 --versions.ie=3.4.0`

Start webdriver with specific version:

`webdriver-manager start --versions.standalone=3.4.0`