# Selenium: Error: WebDriverError: Invalid timeout type specified: ms

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, protractor

I have a problem using Selenium on IE.

When I run npm run e2e:desktop command, Selenium launch and close immediately an IE page. Then, I got this error:

```
E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.

E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: Invalid timeout type specified: ms
```

I launch this command to install selenium:

```
webdriver-manager update --standalone=false --chrome=false --gecko=false --versions.standalone=3.4.0 --versions.chrome=2.25
```

Stack:

IE : 11.0.960019463

Protractor : 5.1.1

Selenium Server Stadalone : 3.141.59

IE web driver : 3.14.0

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug of protractor 5.0.0+ dependencies. You could try to downgrade protractor from 5.1.1 to 5.0.0. Or you could try the following command to update and start the webdriver manager with a specific version:

```
webdriver-manager clean
webdriver-manager update --ie --versions.standalone=3.4.0 --versions.ie=3.4.0
webdriver-manager start --versions.standalone=3.4.0
```

For more information, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681507/protractor-error-webdrivererror-invalid-timeout-type-specified-ms).